# Public Workspaces in Microsoft TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

First, my goal: I am trying to put a directory on a network drive under TFS source control so that we can at least semi-manage versions of the files in that directory.  We will be accessing these files through Visual Studio.

I can easily create a local TFS workspace in VS that maps the correct source control folder to the correct network folder, and it works just as I expect.  Then I saw the advanced options for the workspace that let me: a) make it a server workspace instead of a local workspace, and b) make it public.  Excellent!

However, I can't seem to find a way to get other users on other computers to get to that workspace.  They can see that it exists by using "tf workspaces /owner:*" but nothing inside VS seems to let them be able to select that workspace.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a misunderstanding with the workspace. Your workspace is your local copy of the team's codebase. Choose *Public workspace* if you want to use a **single computer** for a team to collaborate on an effort such as resolving a large number of conflicts, so you can't use this workspace on other computers.

You can only view all the workspaces **you own** (including those on other computers) in VS.

Answer (score -1):

Stop managing code on a shared drive. Shared drives are what you use if you don't have source control. You have source control; use it. People can map a workspace on their machines and get the source code from source control.

Comment: I get the point, and understand that what I'm doing is not "best practice".  The problem is that I *do* have a shared drive, I can't change it, and I am trying to provide at least some control and history over the contents of that drive.  It's not "source" and I specifically don't want people to have local copies.